# does garmin connect and the forerunner 920xt offer triathlon plans

Tags: workout-routines, triathlon

Note according to the [help center](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), this is a specific question about *"gear and gadgets used during exercise"* and NOT a recommendation question.

I want to know if the [Garmin forerunner 920xt](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/into-sports/running/forerunner-920xt/prod137024.html) sports watch supports a triathlon plan on garmin connect....
by that I don't mean a tri plan on a pdf sheet, I mean a schedule in a calendar format which you can *check off* as you train (like the nike+ running app "coach" plans)

I came across [this reddit thread](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which suggests they do have sprint and olympic plans but I want to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have the 910 - but I think it's the same for the 920 as well

Short answer: Yes

Long, and detailed answer:

Browsing on the Training plans inside garmin connect, there are several training plans for either Sprint or Olympic distance.

[image]

Once I selected a plan, and set it's start date

[image]

[image]

It was added to my Connect calendar.

Once within your Connect calendar, you can simply send the plan to your device.

[image]

[image]

- This is an example of a swim practice.

[image]

As you can see, you get the swim for x seconds, only it's not built in as a lap. Do like me: just print the practice, and put it at pool side where you rest anyway :-)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for the detail. The sports watch is a big buy, this whole plan thing just seals the deal for me so it looks like it's worth the money. I only have two more questions: **(A)** Does it by an chance give you fine grain notifications (like 200m swim complete now rest for 30 secs..) **(B)** How do you _"check off"_ each day of training ?

Comment: There are no swim notifications. Just print it, and rest it in the pool side. As for "check off" :-) I guess you need to start and do them :-) It's a per day practice, if you missed one, you can't do it later (unless you push the entire plan forward.